# Структура базы каталога товаров

Tags: mysql, pdo

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой создания средней сложности каталога товаров.
Проблема в основном в том что товары сильно отличаются по характеристикам.
Пример характеристики товаров:
Карнизы, наличники(Название, артикул, цена без грунтовки, цена с грунтовкой, цена с покраской)
Утеплители для труб (Название, артикул, цена, радиус внешней трубы, толщина утеплителя, толщина трубы.)
Опалубка (Название, артикул, цена, высота, толщина, ширина) Характеристики описывал заказчик.

Вопрос состоит в том как лучше делать структуру. 
1)Создать одну таблицу с общими полями (Название, артикул) и вторую таблицу с характеристиками, характеристики отличаются сильно, цены совершенно разные. Насколько удобен подобный метод?
2)Затолкать все в одну таблицу и при добавлении или выдаче выдавать только нужные поля? Понимаю что криво, но хотелось бы иметь только одну таблицу с товарами, связанными ключами с категориями (В дом(Карнизы и наличники), на дачу(Трубы и опалубку))
3) Распихать каждый вид товара в отдельную таблицу.

Подскажите пожалуйста где искать пример или у кого есть подобный опыт, Как грамотно сделать, чтобы это относительно легко масштабировалось, чувствую товаров будет больше и количество характеристик тоже увеличится...

Comment: ваши предложения хранить все в одной таблице, и желания грамотно сделать и масштабирование маловероятно что могут сойтись в одном решении. подобные вопросы о таких каталогах тут уже поднимались и не однократно.

Comment: А вы на этом сайте не пробовали искать "каталог товаров база", много интересного можно найти ... потому что подобные вопросы возникают у людей раз в неделю ... И почти во всех случаях ответ один - EAV (прямо эти 3 буквы можно вбивать в поиск тут и в гугле). Хотя у вас еще цены разных видов, это конечно интереснее, вроде как то же EAV, только думаю отдельный от остальных атрибутов

Comment: @Mike, спасибо. По запросу "EAV" и вправду больше полезной информации. Хорошего дня Вам.